# Python 3 Selenium: can't find element visible on screen

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium

I'm trying to locate and click on an element on a webpage using selenium. The webpage is https://www.innisfil.ca/ using the built in search bar on this webpage and to iterate through the search results by clicking on the next button.

The next button is stored in the span element with the class "search-next" as seen in a piece of the html code from the website below.

```
<font class="search-nav" face="arial,verdana,geneva,lucida" size="-1">
     <span class="search-prev">&lt;&lt;&nbsp;Prev</span>
     <span class="search-prevnext-sep">&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp</span>
     <span class="search-next">
         <a class="search-nav" dir="ltr" href="https://search.freefind.com/find.html?pageid=r&amp;id=47055328&amp;query=environmental+assessment&amp;sbv=j2&amp;ics=1&amp;fr=10" target="">
             <b>Next</b>
             &nbsp;&gt;&gt;
         </a>
     </span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</font>
```

The here the working example code I've written:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

url ='http://www.town.innisfil.on.ca'
munip = "t"
bar_name = 'query'
search_term = "environmental assessment"
next_button_name = "search-next"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

search_bar = driver.find_element_by_name(bar_name)
search_bar.send_keys("house")
search_bar.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

try:
     span = driver.find_element_by_class_name(next_button_name)
     span.find_element_by_tag_name("a").click()
except NoSuchElementException:
     print("Can't find next button")
```

My question is why can I see the button both on the screen in the html yet selenium can't seem to find it? I am not terribly familiar with the ins and outs of html and this might be something very obvious. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search result for the text `house` is displayed within an `iframe` with `id` as `ffse-overlay-ifr`. So you have to switch to the **`ffse-overlay-ifr`** `frame` first. Here is your own code with some simple modifications which works perfect on my `Windows 8` system:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

url ='http://www.town.innisfil.on.ca'
munip = "t"
bar_name = 'query'
search_term = "environmental assessment"
next_button_name = "search-next"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)
search_bar = driver.find_element_by_name("query")
search_bar.send_keys("house")
search_bar.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
driver.switch_to_frame("ffse-overlay")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='search-nav']").click()
print("Next Button Clicked")
```

Console Output:

```
Next Button Clicked
```

Comment: Thank you for your well explained answer!

Comment: @AngeMcAuslan Glad to be able to help you.